# Using XPath with ASP.NET C# Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, gridview, xpath

I'm new in using Xpath with ASP.NET C#. I have a Gridview and am able to Insert/Edit/Delete data from an xml file. However I need to be able to perform the same task using a more complicated xml file. Could someone help me get started as to how I would go about implementing the Xpath Functionality into my code?

**using the following xml ex.1, all functions as expected**:

```
 <root>
  <partNumbers>
    <partid>0</partid>
    <partnumber>796542</partnumber>
  </partNumbers>
  <partNumbers>
    <partid>1</partid>
    <partnumber>225614</partnumber>
  </partNumbers>
  <partNumbers>
    <partid>2</partid>
    <partnumber>123457</partnumber>
  </partNumbers>
</root>
```

...however, I need to perform the same actions using the following xml ex.2 file, Note: The actual file consist of more, but am just using the following for testing:

```
<root>
<pos>
  <partNumbers>
    <partid>0</partid>
    <partnumber>796542</partnumber>
  </partNumbers>
  <partNumbers>
    <partid>1</partid>
    <partnumber>225614</partnumber>
  </partNumbers>
  <partNumbers>
    <partid>2</partid>
    <partnumber>123457</partnumber>
  </partNumbers>
</pos>
</root>
```

...Code behind - I've included the header directives System.Xml and System.Xml.Xpath  (snippet)

```
protected void BindGridView()
{
    DataSet dsgvPartNumber = new DataSet();
    dsgvPartNumber.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/storeUserInfo.xml"));
    gvPartNumber.DataSource = dsgvPartNumber;
    gvPartNumber.DataBind();
    gvPartNumber.ShowFooter = true;
}
```

...the rest are just my functions for insert/edit/ delete, etc, which works fine

.....The Gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvPartNumber" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    onrowdeleting="gvPartNumber_RowDeleting" onrowediting="gvPartNumber_RowEditing"
    onrowupdating="gvPartNumber_RowUpdating" onrowcommand="gvPartNumber_RowCommand"
    ShowFooter="True" Width="482px"
    onrowcancelingedit="gvPartNumber_RowCancelingEdit">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Part ID">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPartID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("partID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPartIDInsert" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblPartID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PartID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Part Number">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPartNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("partNumber") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPartNumberInsert" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblPartNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PartNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True"
                    CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
                    CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnInsert" runat="server" CommandName="insertXMLData">Insert</asp:LinkButton>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
                    CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Width="120px" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

...when I run the page using ex.2 - I get a error: System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'PartID - Could someone please provide me with some direction as to how I would go about using Xpath to resolve this issue?

Comment: I don't see what XPath has to do with this. Were are you using XPath? What problems are you having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work if you change

```
gvPartNumber.DataSource = dsgvPartNumber;
```

to

```
gvPartNumber.DataSource = dsgvPartNumber.Tables["partNumbers"];
```

Probably you have overlooked the second xml is returning two tables in the dataset which is normal behavior. When you are setting your gridview source to this dataset, it is using default table (pos) to bind and data binding fails.

Comment: ...Ok, that makes since, issue resolved. I was overlooking the fact that example 2 is returning two tables. Thank you.